# Docker exited with code 0 on trying to use nodejs , nodemon and subfolder

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have this setup which work fine but recently I moved all my codes to sub folder `functions`.

web get exited with 0  
mongo run fine.

Note : I'm creating that subfolder functions because i'm trying to use firebase.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
    web:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        links:
            - mongo
        volumes:
            - .:/usr/src/app
    mongo:
        image: mongo
        ports:
            - "27018:27017"
        volumes:
            -  mongodata:/data/db
volumes:
    mongodata:
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY functions/package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

RUN npm install -g nodemon

CMD [ "nodemon", "functions/index.js" ]
```

**.dockerignore**

```
node_modules
npm-debug.log
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have checked the current situation like this:

`docker-compose run web bash`

In bash, i have checked folder structure with `ls` and they were coming from root folder. So even you copy your functions folder to docker-image it volumes override the docker-image folder.

I have tried to change web -> volumes value to `- .functions:/usr/src/app` in docker-compose.yml but it didn't work.

So finally I moved `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` files under `functions` folder. And changed the scripts like

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 8080

RUN npm install -g nodemon
CMD nodemon "index.js"
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - mongo
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27018:27017"
```

In my terminal with this command:

`cd functions && docker-compose -f ./docker-compose.yml  up --build --force-recreate`

It works fine but I would recommend you to not move your application under another folder and have a sub npm project. In future you will have different problems because of that like when you run your tests. You need to find a way to keep them in root folder.

Comment: I tried the above acode, it still exited with code 0 :( . I ran `docker-compose build` before running `docker-compose up` again.

Comment: I added `.dockerignore` in question above